# DHTMLX Scheduler recurring year events - Problems with rec_type

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler, recurring-events

I'm trying to add a recurring event in my Database using dhtmlx scheduler. I'm using a full customized Lightbox with my own fields. Daily, weekly and monthly Events will be added perfectly to the database. Maybe i overlooked something

I've tried to save the exact rec_type like the monthly event, because they are using the nearly the same template, there is only one difference between them. I changed "month" into "year".

At the end, my entry looks like this:

```
{
    end_date: "09.06.2026 12:00"
    id: "a97ede9d-372f-4360-9fdb-e97e26aaacf8"
    rec_type: "year_5_4_1#09/06/2026"
    start_date: "05.09.2019 12:00"
    text: "test12345"
}
```

I expect the output of all events on the first thursday in may until 2026. Maybe you can help me to find out, where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If recurring events start in May, the start_date also must contain May. I.e.

```
start_date: "05.05.2020 12:00"
```

The client side gets data from the rec_type field as a string of the following format:

```
[type]_[count]_[day]_[count2]_[days]#[extra]
```

where:

- type - the type of repetition: 'day','week','month','year'.
- count - the interval between events in the "type" units.
- day and count2 - define a day of a month ( first Monday, third Friday, etc ).
- days - a comma-separated list of affected week days.
- extra - extra info that can be used to change the presentation of recurring details.

So, rec_type for each first Thursday in May must be:

```
rec_type: "year_1_4_1_"
```

[Demo](http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/766eed51a) to check how it works.

If you need more details about **rec_type** property, please find them in [docs](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/recurring_events.html#serversideintegration).